# I cant put a background in my code in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to put a background in my web im just staring with a tutorial my code is like this

```
<html xmlns="http:/www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>PARIS DROP OUT</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header1">
        <h1>THE DROP OUTS</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="#container_div">
        <img id="drop" src="img/SHOCK.jpg" />
        <background-image: src="img/background" />
        <p class="red">ESTA PAGINA ES DE LOS LOCOS</p>
        <p> Nowadays it's easy to put together a web presence using social media and a personal landing page, but if you want to actually make your own web site you're going to need to learn HTML and CSS. Fortunately, we can help. </p>
    </div>   
</body>
```

MY CSS LOOKS LIKE THIS:

```
<code> #container_div {
width:1800px;
height: :1800px;
background:red;
```

I try putting an image it doesn't work either 
I have the exact same code that its on the tutorial and I don't see a background no matter what I change

Comment: CSS has to be in `<style>` tags, not `<code>`.

Comment: Remove the code tag complete and does not even use <style> if it is a dedicated css file.

Answer (score 0):

Your div should be `<div id="container_div">` (note: *without* the #)
The CSS selector `#container_div` means "any element with the id="container_div"

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

css code to change background color

```
Background-color:red;
```

css code to change background image

```
Background-image:url();
```

your css class:

```
#container_div {
width:1800px;
height:1800px;
Background-color:red;
}
```